# Write a function to run through a series of commands, zsh

Tags: function, ffmpeg, find, touch, zsh

I am trying to write a function to run through a series of commands, but I have no idea where to start.

This is the series of commands I want to run.

```
find ./ -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -vcodec libx264 -vf scale=854:480 -cpu-used 5 -threads 8 "${0%%.mp4}-copy.mp4"' {} \;
touch -r video.mp4 video-copy.mp4
rm -rf video.mp4
mv video-copy.mp4 video.mp4
find ./ -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'qt-faststart "$0" "${0%%.mp4}-fs.mp4"' {} \;
touch -r video.mp4 video-fs.mp4
rm -rf video.mp4
mv video-fs.mp4 video.mp4
find ./ -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -vf scale=-1:480 -cpu-used 5 -threads 8 "${0%%.mp4}.webm"' {} \;
touch -r video.mp4 video.webm
find ./ -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -ss 00:00:10 -vframes 1 -r 1 -vf scale=-1:480 -f image2 "${0%%.mp4}.jpg"' {} \;
touch -r video.mp4 video.jpg
mv video.jpg thumbnail.jpg
```

Can someone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your commands in `<funcname> () { ... }`.

```
foo () {
    find ./ -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -vcodec libx264 -vf scale=854:480 -cpu-used 5 -threads 8 "${0%%.mp4}-copy.mp4"' {} \;
    touch -r video.mp4 video-copy.mp4
    rm -rf video.mp4
    mv video-copy.mp4 video.mp4
    find ./ -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'qt-faststart "$0" "${0%%.mp4}-fs.mp4"' {} \;
    touch -r video.mp4 video-fs.mp4
    rm -rf video.mp4
    mv video-fs.mp4 video.mp4
    find ./ -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -vf scale=-1:480 -cpu-used 5 -threads 8 "${0%%.mp4}.webm"' {} \;
    touch -r video.mp4 video.webm
    find ./ -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -ss 00:00:10 -vframes 1 -r 1 -vf scale=-1:480 -f image2 "${0%%.mp4}.jpg"' {} \;
    touch -r video.mp4 video.jpg
    mv video.jpg thumbnail.jpg
}
```